# How can I render a shiny datatables as a link

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

Say I have one column of a data.frame that has a list of urls e.g

```
urlCol
http://mysite1.com
http://mysite2.com
```

How do I set that as a clickable link in renderDataTable?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url can be wrapped in an anchor tag:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(
  list(ui = fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput("myTable")
  )
  , server = function(input, output, session){
    output$myTable <- renderDataTable({
      data.frame(name = c("GOOGLE", "YAHOO")
                 , url = c("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">http://www.google.com</a>"
                           , "http://yahoo.com")
                           )
    })
  })
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. For anyone else needing to paste raw text in from a data.frame, I found it simpler to use single quotes rather than the escape character viz 'http://www.google.com' rather than \"http://www.google.com\"

Comment: This now requires that you set the escape parameter in renderDataTable to False. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269585/in-latest-shiny-html-rendering-code-breaks-in-renderdatatable