# In Latest shiny, html rendering code breaks in renderDataTable

Tags: r, shiny

Below code used to work well till I upgraded my shiny. Now it just prints out the html text. Does not render it as html

ui.R

`dataTableOutput("grid")`

server.R

```
testLinks<-function(){
serial<-(1:2)
websites<-c("www.google.com","www.yahoo.com")
Link<-paste0("<a href=\"",websites,"\" target=\"_blank\">", websites,"</a>")
df<-data.frame(serial, websites,Link)
df
}

output$grid<-renderDataTable(testLinks())
```

Now it just renders the links as html text

Before the upgrade, it uses to render them as html links.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The escape argument in renderDataTable needs to be set to FALSE. I am assuming the default has been changed in this release. Causing my code to break. This has been fixed, by explicitly setting escape paramater to FALSE.